# mouse pointer no responding fast?

Tags: 13.10

the pointer/cursor not responding in the same speed as I move the mouse acting slow, even in the fastest speed still no responding fast as I move the mouse any idea what is the problem on this anybody?

Comment: You turned the acceleration up all the way?  If so try turning the sensitivity down all the way. My current mouse responded the same way when I replaced it, not sure why, but tuning down the sensitivity fixed it, in fact I had to turn the acceleration back down after, it was moving too fast....

Answer (score 0):

I turned off system setting>security&privacy>files&applications>Record file and application usage switch. 
My mouse seems to moves smoothly after I turn it off. If it did not work for you, I think something like that must be the reason.